# Running SailsJS through Docker Compose - Blank Screen

Tags: docker, sails.js

Hoping someone can help me. I am trying to run my app through Docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
ENV NODE_ENV development
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: node app.js --port=3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgresql
      POSTGRES_DB: postgresql
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, the app is running fine and I can see Sails has been lifted. When visiting the url http://localhost:3000 I get a blank page, yet in the terminal, I see that the page has been viewed and a response sent. There are no error messages and I can see the Sails favicon in the browser.

I am running native Docker in Windows 10 and I have PHP apps that run fine. As a side note, if I try to run sails-disk as my datastore, it has issues saving data to disk, not sure if that is related or not, but it could help.

Edit: This is my package.json file in case it helps. I initially ran `sails new sails-app` and added postgresql and momentjs which means it's fairly standard.

```
{
  "name": "sails-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "async": "2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "sails": "^1.0.1",
    "sails-hook-apianalytics": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-hook-organics": "^0.13.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
    "sails-postgresql": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3",
    "@sailshq/htmlhint": "^0.9.16",
    "@sailshq/lesshint": "^4.6.6",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node app.js",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run custom-tests && echo 'Done.'",
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo '✔  Your .js files look so good.' && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && htmlhint -c ./.htmlhintrc views/**/**/**/**/**/**/*.ejs && echo '✔  So do your .ejs files.' && lesshint assets/styles/ --max-warnings=0 && echo '✔  Your .less files look good, too.'",
    "custom-tests": "echo \"(No other custom tests yet.)\" && echo",
    "deploy": "echo 'This script assumes a dead-simple, opinionated setup on Heroku.' && echo 'But, of course, you can deploy your app anywhere you like.' && echo '(Node.js/Sails.js apps are supported on all modern hosting platforms.)' && echo && echo 'Warning: Specifically, this script assumes you are on the master branch, and that your app can be deployed simply by force-pushing on top of the *deploy* branch.  It will also temporarily use a local *predeploy* branch for preparing assets, that it will delete after it finishes.  Please make sure there is nothing you care about on either of these two branches!!!' && echo '' && echo '' && echo 'Preparing to deploy...' && echo '--' && git status && echo '' && echo '--' && echo 'I hope you are on the master branch and have everything committed/pulled/pushed and are completely up to date and stuff.' && echo '********************************************'  && echo '** IF NOT THEN PLEASE PRESS <CTRL+C> NOW! **' && echo '********************************************' && echo 'Press CTRL+C to cancel.' && echo '(you have five seconds)' && sleep 1 && echo '...4' && sleep 1 && echo '...3' && sleep 1 && echo '...2' && sleep 1 && echo '...1' && sleep 1  && echo '' && echo 'Alright, here we go.  No turning back now!' && echo 'Trying to switch to master branch...' && git checkout master && echo && echo 'OK.  Now wiping node_modules/ and running npm install...' && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && (git add package-lock.json && git commit -am 'AUTOMATED COMMIT: Did fresh npm install before deploying, and it caused something relevant (probably the package-lock.json file) to change!  This commit tracks that change.' || true) && echo 'Deploying as version:' && npm version patch && echo '' && git push origin master && git push --tags && (git branch -D predeploy > /dev/null 2>&1 || true) && git checkout -b predeploy && (echo 'Now building+minifying assets for production...' && echo '(Hang tight, this could take a while.)' && echo && node node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt buildProd || (echo && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo 'IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!  IMPORTANT!' && echo 'ERROR: Could not compile assets for production!' && echo && echo 'Attempting to recover automatically by stashing, ' && echo 'switching back to the master branch, and then ' && echo 'deleting the predeploy branch... ' && echo && echo 'After this, please fix the issues logged above' && echo 'and push that up.  Then, try deploying again.' && echo '------------------------------------------' && echo && echo 'Staging, deleting the predeploy branch, and switching back to master...' && git stash && git checkout master && git branch -D predeploy && false)) && mv www .www && git add .www && node -e 'sailsrc = JSON.parse(require(\"fs\").readFileSync(\"./.sailsrc\", \"utf8\"));  if (sailsrc.paths&&sailsrc.paths.public !== undefined || sailsrc.hooks&&sailsrc.hooks.grunt !== undefined) { throw new Error(\"Cannot complete deployment script: .sailsrc file has conflicting contents!  Please throw away this midway-complete deployment, switch back to your original branch (master), remove the conflicting stuff from .sailsrc, then commit and push that up.\"); }  sailsrc.paths = sailsrc.paths || {};  sailsrc.paths.public = \"./.www\";   sailsrc.hooks = sailsrc.hooks || {};  sailsrc.hooks.grunt = false;  require(\"fs\").writeFileSync(\"./.sailsrc\", JSON.stringify(sailsrc))' && git commit -am 'AUTOMATED COMMIT: Automatically bundling compiled assets as part of deploy, updating the EJS layout and .sailsrc file accordingly.' && git push origin predeploy && git checkout master && git push origin +predeploy:deploy && git push --tags && git branch -D predeploy && git push origin :predeploy && echo '' && echo '--' && echo 'OK, done.  It should be live momentarily on your staging environment.' && echo '(if you get impatient, check the Heroku dashboard for status)' && echo && echo 'Staging environment:' && echo ' –•  https://staging.example.com' && echo '       (hold ⌘ and click to open links in the terminal)' && echo && echo 'Please review that to make sure it looks good.' && echo 'When you are ready to go to production, visit your pipeline on Heroku and press the PROMOTE TO PRODUCTION button.'"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/anonymous node/sails user/sails-app.git"
  },
  "author": "anonymous node/sails user",
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your database required from the beginning of your app's life? You are not waiting until the DB is initialized.

Comment: it's impossible to reproduce as sails.js has no official docker image, can you share `package.json` and everything relevant?

Comment: @trust512 If I try to run it without a db and use sails-disk instead, it isn't able to save the data when running migrations during initial start up.

Comment: @vitr I have updated the question and added my package.json contents. It's pretty much a standard install using "sails new sails-app"

Comment: localhost:3000 works just fine with the default app, from where are you running `docker-compose` ? Is it shared drive with docker?

Comment: @vitr I am running it on PowerShell from my Windows 10 machine using Docker for Windows. EDIT: If it works for you, then I'm going to assume this is a bug with Windows or my install. I'll try it on another machine to see if it works there.

Comment: tested with powershell as well, just keep in mind, in general, it's a bad practice to create an app in Windows and then copy it to linux container, you should create the sails app in the node container you use in your docker file